# suspension during searching through text file

Tags: java, regex

I wrote program that should search email address in text file, it works fine in small/tight file but in large it often suspend. I am using regex and pattern that I found in somewhere at Stack Overflow(is great).

Program looks like:

```
    Set<String> emailList = new HashSet<>();

    try {
        File plik = new File("plik2.txt");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
       new InputStreamReader(
                  new FileInputStream(plik), "UTF8"));

        Matcher m;
        String line;
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*(?:(?:(?:[^()<>@,;:\\\\\".\\[\\] \\000-\\031]+(?:(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])+|\\Z|(?=[\\[\"()<>@,;:\\\\\".\\[\\]]))|\"(?:[^\\\"\\r\\\\]|\\\\.|(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t]))*\"(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*)(?:\\.(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\\\\".\\[\\] \\000-\\031]+(?:(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])+|\\Z|(?=[\\[\"()<>@,;:\\\\\".\\[\\]]))|\"(?:[^\\\"\\r\\\\]|\\\\.|(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t]))*\"(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*))*@(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\\\\".\\[\\] \\000-\\031]+(?:(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])+|\\Z|(?=[\\[\"()<>@,;:\\\\\".\\[\\]]))|\\[([^\\[\\]\\r\\\\]|\\\\.)*\\](?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*)(?:\\.(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\\\\".\\[\\] \\000-\\031]+(?:(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])+|\\Z|(?=[\\[\"()<>@,;:\\\\\".\\[\\]]))|\\[([^\\[\\]\\r\\\\]|\\\\.)*\\](?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*))*|(?:[^()<>@,;:\\\\\".\\[\\] \\000-\\031]+(?:(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])+|\\Z|(?=[\\[\"()<>@,;:\\\\\".\\[\\]]))|\"(?:[^\\\"\\r\\\\]|\\\\.|(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t]))*\"(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*)*\\<(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*(?:@(?:[^()<>@,;:\\\\\".\\[\\] \\000-\\031]+(?:(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])+|\\Z|(?=[\\[\"()<>@,;:\\\\\".\\[\\]]))|\\[([^\\[\\]\\r\\\\]|\\\\.)*\\](?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*)(?:\\.(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\\\\".\\[\\] \\000-\\031]+(?:(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])+|\\Z|(?=[\\[\"()<>@,;:\\\\\".\\[\\]]))|\\[([^\\[\\]\\r\\\\]|\\\\.)*\\](?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*))*(?:,@(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\\\\".\\[\\] \\000-\\031]+(?:(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])+|\\Z|(?=[\\[\"()<>@,;:\\\\\".\\[\\]]))|\\[([^\\[\\]\\r\\\\]|\\\\.)*\\](?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*)(?:\\.(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\\\\".\\[\\] \\000-\\031]+(?:(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])+|\\Z|(?=[\\[\"()<>@,;:\\\\\".\\[\\]]))|\\[([^\\[\\]\\r\\\\]|\\\\.)*\\](?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*))*)*:(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*)?(?:[^()<>@,;:\\\\\".\\[\\] \\000-\\031]+(?:(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])+|\\Z|(?=[\\[\"()<>@,;:\\\\\".\\[\\]]))|\"(?:[^\\\"\\r\\\\]|\\\\.|(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t]))*\"(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*)(?:\\.(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\\\\".\\[\\] \\000-\\031]+(?:(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])+|\\Z|(?=[\\[\"()<>@,;:\\\\\".\\[\\]]))|\"(?:[^\\\"\\r\\\\]|\\\\.|(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t]))*\"(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*))*@(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\\\\".\\[\\] \\000-\\031]+(?:(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])+|\\Z|(?=[\\[\"()<>@,;:\\\\\".\\[\\]]))|\\[([^\\[\\]\\r\\\\]|\\\\.)*\\](?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*)(?:\\.(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\\\\".\\[\\] \\000-\\031]+(?:(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])+|\\Z|(?=[\\[\"()<>@,;:\\\\\".\\[\\]]))|\\[([^\\[\\]\\r\\\\]|\\\\.)*\\](?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*))*\\>(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*)|(?:[^()<>@,;:\\\\\".\\[\\] \\000-\\031]+(?:(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])+|\\Z|(?=[\\[\"()<>@,;:\\\\\".\\[\\]]))|\"(?:[^\\\"\\r\\\\]|\\\\.|(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t]))*\"(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*)*:(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*(?:(?:(?:[^()<>@,;:\\\\\".\\[\\] \\000-\\031]+(?:(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])+|\\Z|(?=[\\[\"()<>@,;:\\\\\".\\[\\]]))|\"(?:[^\\\"\\r\\\\]|\\\\.|(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t]))*\"(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*)(?:\\.(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\\\\".\\[\\] \\000-\\031]+(?:(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])+|\\Z|(?=[\\[\"()<>@,;:\\\\\".\\[\\]]))|\"(?:[^\\\"\\r\\\\]|\\\\.|(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t]))*\"(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*))*@(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\\\\".\\[\\] \\000-\\031]+(?:(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])+|\\Z|(?=[\\[\"()<>@,;:\\\\\".\\[\\]]))|\\[([^\\[\\]\\r\\\\]|\\\\.)*\\](?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*)(?:\\.(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\\\\".\\[\\] \\000-\\031]+(?:(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])+|\\Z|(?=[\\[\"()<>@,;:\\\\\".\\[\\]]))|\\[([^\\[\\]\\r\\\\]|\\\\.)*\\](?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*))*|(?:[^()<>@,;:\\\\\".\\[\\] \\000-\\031]+(?:(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])+|\\Z|(?=[\\[\"()<>@,;:\\\\\".\\[\\]]))|\"(?:[^\\\"\\r\\\\]|\\\\.|(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t]))*\"(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*)*\\<(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*(?:@(?:[^()<>@,;:\\\\\".\\[\\] \\000-\\031]+(?:(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])+|\\Z|(?=[\\[\"()<>@,;:\\\\\".\\[\\]]))|\\[([^\\[\\]\\r\\\\]|\\\\.)*\\](?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*)(?:\\.(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\\\\".\\[\\] \\000-\\031]+(?:(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])+|\\Z|(?=[\\[\"()<>@,;:\\\\\".\\[\\]]))|\\[([^\\[\\]\\r\\\\]|\\\\.)*\\](?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*))*(?:,@(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\\\\".\\[\\] \\000-\\031]+(?:(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])+|\\Z|(?=[\\[\"()<>@,;:\\\\\".\\[\\]]))|\\[([^\\[\\]\\r\\\\]|\\\\.)*\\](?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*)(?:\\.(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\\\\".\\[\\] \\000-\\031]+(?:(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])+|\\Z|(?=[\\[\"()<>@,;:\\\\\".\\[\\]]))|\\[([^\\[\\]\\r\\\\]|\\\\.)*\\](?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*))*)*:(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*)?(?:[^()<>@,;:\\\\\".\\[\\] \\000-\\031]+(?:(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])+|\\Z|(?=[\\[\"()<>@,;:\\\\\".\\[\\]]))|\"(?:[^\\\"\\r\\\\]|\\\\.|(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t]))*\"(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*)(?:\\.(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\\\\".\\[\\] \\000-\\031]+(?:(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])+|\\Z|(?=[\\[\"()<>@,;:\\\\\".\\[\\]]))|\"(?:[^\\\"\\r\\\\]|\\\\.|(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t]))*\"(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*))*@(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\\\\".\\[\\] \\000-\\031]+(?:(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])+|\\Z|(?=[\\[\"()<>@,;:\\\\\".\\[\\]]))|\\[([^\\[\\]\\r\\\\]|\\\\.)*\\](?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*)(?:\\.(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\\\\".\\[\\] \\000-\\031]+(?:(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])+|\\Z|(?=[\\[\"()<>@,;:\\\\\".\\[\\]]))|\\[([^\\[\\]\\r\\\\]|\\\\.)*\\](?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*))*\\>(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*)(?:,\\s*(?:(?:[^()<>@,;:\\\\\".\\[\\] \\000-\\031]+(?:(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])+|\\Z|(?=[\\[\"()<>@,;:\\\\\".\\[\\]]))|\"(?:[^\\\"\\r\\\\]|\\\\.|(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t]))*\"(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*)(?:\\.(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\\\\".\\[\\] \\000-\\031]+(?:(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])+|\\Z|(?=[\\[\"()<>@,;:\\\\\".\\[\\]]))|\"(?:[^\\\"\\r\\\\]|\\\\.|(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t]))*\"(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*))*@(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\\\\".\\[\\] \\000-\\031]+(?:(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])+|\\Z|(?=[\\[\"()<>@,;:\\\\\".\\[\\]]))|\\[([^\\[\\]\\r\\\\]|\\\\.)*\\](?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*)(?:\\.(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\\\\".\\[\\] \\000-\\031]+(?:(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])+|\\Z|(?=[\\[\"()<>@,;:\\\\\".\\[\\]]))|\\[([^\\[\\]\\r\\\\]|\\\\.)*\\](?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*))*|(?:[^()<>@,;:\\\\\".\\[\\] \\000-\\031]+(?:(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])+|\\Z|(?=[\\[\"()<>@,;:\\\\\".\\[\\]]))|\"(?:[^\\\"\\r\\\\]|\\\\.|(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t]))*\"(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*)*\\<(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*(?:@(?:[^()<>@,;:\\\\\".\\[\\] \\000-\\031]+(?:(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])+|\\Z|(?=[\\[\"()<>@,;:\\\\\".\\[\\]]))|\\[([^\\[\\]\\r\\\\]|\\\\.)*\\](?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*)(?:\\.(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\\\\".\\[\\] \\000-\\031]+(?:(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])+|\\Z|(?=[\\[\"()<>@,;:\\\\\".\\[\\]]))|\\[([^\\[\\]\\r\\\\]|\\\\.)*\\](?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*))*(?:,@(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\\\\".\\[\\] \\000-\\031]+(?:(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])+|\\Z|(?=[\\[\"()<>@,;:\\\\\".\\[\\]]))|\\[([^\\[\\]\\r\\\\]|\\\\.)*\\](?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*)(?:\\.(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\\\\".\\[\\] \\000-\\031]+(?:(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])+|\\Z|(?=[\\[\"()<>@,;:\\\\\".\\[\\]]))|\\[([^\\[\\]\\r\\\\]|\\\\.)*\\](?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*))*)*:(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*)?(?:[^()<>@,;:\\\\\".\\[\\] \\000-\\031]+(?:(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])+|\\Z|(?=[\\[\"()<>@,;:\\\\\".\\[\\]]))|\"(?:[^\\\"\\r\\\\]|\\\\.|(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t]))*\"(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*)(?:\\.(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\\\\".\\[\\] \\000-\\031]+(?:(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])+|\\Z|(?=[\\[\"()<>@,;:\\\\\".\\[\\]]))|\"(?:[^\\\"\\r\\\\]|\\\\.|(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t]))*\"(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*))*@(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\\\\".\\[\\] \\000-\\031]+(?:(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])+|\\Z|(?=[\\[\"()<>@,;:\\\\\".\\[\\]]))|\\[([^\\[\\]\\r\\\\]|\\\\.)*\\](?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*)(?:\\.(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*(?:[^()<>@,;:\\\\\".\\[\\] \\000-\\031]+(?:(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])+|\\Z|(?=[\\[\"()<>@,;:\\\\\".\\[\\]]))|\\[([^\\[\\]\\r\\\\]|\\\\.)*\\](?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*))*\\>(?:(?:\\r\\n)?[ \\t])*))*)?;\\s*)"); // the expression

        System.out.println("<<<===START===>>>");

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);                
            m = p.matcher(line); // the source
            while(m.find()) {
                emailList.add(m.group());
            }
        }
        System.out.println("<<<---KONIEC--->>>\n\n");
        reader.close();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }  catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And it works nice for example for:

> something something something something something something something
>   something something  something something something something v
>   something something something something something something v
>   something
>
> something something www@wwp.pl something something@wp.pl
>   something@gmail.com somethingsomething something something something
>   something v something v something v something 
>   somethingsomethingsomethingsomething something something something
>   something something something

But not for:

> > ----- Original Message ----- From: Kel To: buickman@generalwatch.com Sent: Saturday, February 25, 2006 4:57 PM Subject: Wagoner the
> >     Terminator
>
> Dear Buickman,
>
> A few months ago I discovered your General Watch website and have been
>   hooked ever since. I work in the auto industry. In fact, I worked for
>   General Motors for several years when I began my career more than 10
>   years ago. Having loved GM's products my whole life, Chevys in
>   particular, I remember thinking back then that this was my dream job.
>   I soon discovered otherwise. I found a company that was shockingly
>   unenthusiastic about cars and shockingly enthusiastic about office
>   politics and red tape. I remember one day when Rick Wagoner came to
>   our facility in Southeast Michigan to speak to us about some forgotten
>   topic. He was the President of NAO back then. I knew then and there
>   that he was not the right person to lead GM into the future!! By the
>   time I left the company, I believed in my heart, and still do, that GM
>   would never learn its lessons or turn itself around until it was too
>   late.
>
> As I've read your editorials, I've come to recall the scene in the
>   movie "The Terminator" in which Kyle Reese explains to Sarah Connor in
>   a parking garage the severity of her current situation. After he tells
>   her that he's from the future, she tries to escape from the car in
>   which they're sitting. He prevents this, so she bites his hand. Kyle
>   Reese says to Sarah Connor, "Terminators don't feel pain. I do. Don't
>   do that again." Sarah Connor attempts another escape, which Kyle Reese
>   again prevents.
>
> She struggles, and he says to her, "Listen, and understand!! That
>   Terminator is out there! It can't be reasoned with! It can't be
>   bargained with! It doesn't feel pity, or remorse, or fear! And it
>   absolutely will not stop, ever, until you are dead!!" It dawned on me
>   that these words could just as easily serve as a warning that Rick
>   Wagoner (i.e., the Terminator) is out to kill General Motors (i.e.,
>   the target or victim, like Sarah Connor). I suppose people like
>   yourself or Jerome York would be taking on the role of Kyle Reese. I
>   just hope GM can survive like Sarah Connor.
>
> Thank you for your time.
>
> Kel - car-guy@earthlink.net

can someone explain me what in my code is wrong ?

Cheers ;D

Comment: Don't use something you have no idea of how it works. Try a regex like this instead: `\\S+@\\S+?(\\.\\w+)+`, which might contain false positives (or even miss certain very rare valid addresses) but those can then be processed afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your regexp takes a lot of time to be checked on a big text.

I'd advise searching for words that contain **@** sign and after you've found such words, checking them with your regexp. This can speed up the process significantly.

Comment: It works, thanks You very much Bart Kiers and svz, it was soo simple